# add more views to tabbarController in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I drag a `TabBarController` to the storyboard and it contains tow views by default, now I want to add a third view to the tabbarController by dragging a viewController to the storyboard and add relation by ctrl drag but it seems the added view is not the same relationship with the default ones. its relation line is not forked at the same point

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: depends on the position in the storyboard but this is unrrelevant, in fact the only important thing is the relation type, and this should be viewControllers type

Answer (score 0):

kindly go to this link to learn about tab bar using storyboard

https://www.journaldev.com/10590/ios-tab-bar-controller-with-storyboards